# Why AWS athena creating my table as a string instead of an array of nested objects

Tags: amazon-athena

Instead of a nested table all I get is one very long title containing the sql command but no errors. Why is it working but not actually inputing the json data correctly?

```
CREATE external TABLE ranked (
    airlineRankings array<struct<
    overall_rating:TINYINT,
    seat_comfort_rating:TINYINT,
    cabin_staff_rating:TINYINT,
    food_beverages_rating:TINYINT,
    inflight_entertainment_rating:TINYINT,
    ground_service_rating:TINYINT,
    wifi_connectivity_rating:TINYINT,
    value_money_rating:TINYINT,
    recommended:TINYINT,
    review_amount:TINYINT,
    count:TINYINT,
    iata:string,
    icao:string,
    airline_link:string,
    call_sign:string,
    country:string,
    airline:string
      >>
      )
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
    LOCATION 's3://**********/'
```

JSON data format:

```
{
    "airlineRankings": [{
        "iata": "",
        "icao": "EVY",
        "airline_link": "34 Squadron, Royal Australian Air Force",
        "call_sign": "",
        "country": "Australia",
        "airline": "34 Squadron, Royal Australian Air Force",
        "overall_rating": 0,
        "seat_comfort_rating": 0,
        "cabin_staff_rating": 0,
        "food_beverages_rating": 0,
        "inflight_entertainment_rating": 0,
        "ground_service_rating": 0,
        "wifi_connectivity_rating": 0,
        "value_money_rating": 0,
        "recommended": 0,
        "review_amount": 0
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your DDL is fine. If you are having problems with querying the array, you are probably missing the "unnesting" of the array object.

A sample query for your structure would look like this:

```
select myRecord.icao from ranked
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(airlinerankings) AS myTable (myRecord);
```

Comment: HIVE_CURSOR_ERROR: Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: A JSONObject text must end with '}' at 2 [character 3 line 1]

Recive this error. It's a valid json ....

Comment: Could it be that your JSON does contain \n characters?

Comment: I added the JSON data format to original question. yeah, some of the string values have special characters not keys.

Comment: Multiline JSONs are not supported by Athena so far. If I use your sample data and remove all formatting (put it all in one line), the query runs fine.